# Recursively decrement a list by 1

Tags: python, recursion

Very quick and easy homework question. I have it running ok but I think there's a better
way to do it. A more Pythonic way.
Here's my code to recursively decrement each element of a list by 1.

```
l = range(30)  
def recurseDecrMap(l, x = []):  
    if len(l) == 0:  
        return []  
    else:  
        x.append(l[0] -1)  
    recurseDecrMap(l[1:], x)  
    return x
```

So thanks for any input. I'm trying to learn to do better recursion. Having trouble getting
the knack of it.

Comment: @Haidro Linked this, you should see why `x=[]` as a default argument is a bad idea: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-in-python-the-mutable-default-argument

Comment: The Pythonic way is to not use recursion.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use only one argument, in my opinion it is simpler:

```
def recurseDecrMap(l):  
    if not l:  
        return []  
    else:
        return [l[0]-1] + recurseDecrMap(l[1:])
```

But as @jamylak pointed out, the complexity of this algorithm is O(N^2), since `l[1:]` creates a new list with references to the rest of the items in the list.

If you need efficiency, I'd recommend you using list comprehensions ([Haidro's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16257858/recursively-decrment-a-list-by-1/16257907#16257907)), but I suppose it is not a priority if you want it only for learning purposes.

Comment: But also O(N^2), although definitely cleaner and will suffice in most situations

Comment: I would suggest doing `if not l` instead of `if len(l) == 0` when checking for an empty list.

Comment: @Volatility - why? (I used it in my own answer, but for no real reason)

Comment: @Elazar [PEP8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#programming-recommendations) says to "use the fact that empty sequences are false"

Comment: @AmineHajyoussef even so, many would say it is less pythonic than `not l`. And you couldn't argue that `not l` isn't readable...

Answer (score 25):

Probably *less* pythonic, but there:

```
def recurseDecrMap(l):
    return [l[0]-1] + recurseDecrMap(l[1:]) if l else []
```

Comment: I still think the syntax of the python ternary statement is backwards (coming from a c background).  It's worth knowing that your answer can equivalently be expressed as `return [l[0] - 1] + l and recursiveDecrMap(l[1:]) or []`

Comment: @sapi It's worth knowing that your suggestion can easily make you write *subtly incorrect* code. if the `and *` part happens to be false, and is different from the right-hand of the `or` part.

Comment: @Elazar - sure, but short circuiting of operators is defined behaviour, which it's really hard to screw up

Comment: @sapi short-circuiting doesn't have anything to do with this. What Elazar meant is that `A and B or C` if **not** equivalent to `B if A else C`, since, in the case that `A` is true but the value of `B` is considered false, the first expression returns `C` while the second, correctly, returns `B`.

Comment: @Bakuriu - of course, but that's just how short circuiting of operators works.  There's nothing complicated going on here, and in the example given, they are equivalent.

Comment: @sapi It doesn't matter. This kind of usage is a bad idea; you can use it on your own peril, but please *don't* encourage other people to do the same, just because you think `A if E else B` is backwards.

Comment: @Elazar - it's hardly a bad thing to teach people how boolean operators work in python (or most other languages); but feel free to use whatever you prefer in your own code.

Answer (score 9):

For what it's worth, this is a terrible way to learn about recursion, because you're using it to do something that is not inherently recursive.  If your teacher really is asking you to write a program that decrements the elements of a list like `[1, 2, 3, 4]` *recursively*, then shame on him/her.

As Haidro noted, the most Pythonic way to solve this problem is to just iterate over the list using a list comprehension

```
[i - 1 for i in l]
```

As a loop, this is

```
def decr(l):
    a = []
    for i in l:
        a.append(i - 1)
    return a
```

Recursion is useful if you want to solve the same problem at arbitrary levels of *depth*.  For example, say you had something like `[1, [2, 3], [[4], 5]]` and you wanted to decrement each number by 1, while maintaining the list structure. In that case, a recursive solution would use the iterative solution for the base case, and call itself for the recursive case.

```
def decr_recursive(l):
    a = []
    for i in l:
        if isinstance(i, list):
            a.append(decr_recursive(i))
        else:
            a.append(i - 1)
    return a
```

This can be easily modified if you want to support more than just lists or integers.

```
>>> decr([1, [2, 3], [[4], 5]])
[0, [1, 2], [[3], 4]]
```

*This* is the sort of problem that is very difficult to solve without using recursion, but is easy to solve with it. What you are asking is the sort of problem that is easy to solve without recursion (it's just a simple iteration over a list for God's sake), but somewhat difficult to solve with it.

Some reasons why you should avoid recursion in Python

- It's harder to read. Compare `[i - 1 for i in l]`, or even the explicit loop, to something like

  ```
  def decr(l):
      if not l:
          return []
      return [l[0] - 1] + decr(l[:1])
  ```
- Calling a function in Python can be expensive. I get roughly the same timings as Ashwini Chaudhary on my computer. But `[i - 1 for i in range(10**4)]` takes 559 µs on my computer. That's three orders of magnitude faster than the fastest recursive method.
- Recursive functions don't work past 1000 calls unless you set the recursion limit higher.  You may have noticed the `sys.setrecursionlimit(10**5)` call in Ashwini Chaudhary's answer.  This is necessary because without it, each call would lead to a `RuntimeError: maximum recursion depth exceeded` following a huge traceback.  But even with this, a little bigger list would still lead to a recursion limit.  And according to the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.setrecursionlimit), there is a top limit for every OS, and setting it too high can lead to a crash.
- Recursive functions are harder to debug. Not only do they pollute your stack traces with hundreds of calls from the same function, but they are conceptually harder to follow, because the same part of the same function is being used in different ways, depending on which level in the stack you are in. The natural human way of thinking is iterative. We do things one at a time. Our own brains' "stacks" are only a few levels deep, so we have a very hard time solving problems in a recursive way, like "let me start solving a problem, but before I finish, let me solve another problem, and then when I'm done, I'll finish the original problem. And in the smaller problem, I may do the same thing, so that I get several levels deep before I finish." That's why you walk into the kitchen to get a pen, then you see a candy bar and start eating it, and when you are done, you forget about the pen. You "recursed" a level, from the pen problem to the candy bar problem, and your mental stack got too deep (just two levels, but that's enough). If you had instead grabbed the candy bar, but before you opened it and started eating it, also found the pen (the best iterative analouge I could come up with), you would do both without forgetting either. The way you should solve problems in programs should be exactly the same way you solve them in your head, because that's the only way you will understand what your code is doing.  Python is such a great language because its high level interface let's you do exactly that (at least more often than in lower-level languages). *Use this fact!*

Comment: Thanks. Why does it do that?

Comment: Because it is inside an item of a list, so in that case 4 spaces mean the normal level of indentation.

Answer (score 7):

Here's the worst way - using [Fixed Point Combinator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_combinator):

```
Y = lambda g: (lambda f: g(lambda arg: f(f)(arg))) (lambda f: g(lambda arg: f(f)(arg)))
recurseDecrMap = Y(lambda f: lambda l: [l[0]-1] + f(l[1:]) if l else [])
```

Comment: but *really* functional :P

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simple pythonic way:

```
>>> mylist = range(30)
>>> def func(l):
...     return [i-1 for i in l]
>>> func(mylist)
[-1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28]
```

Explanation:

I used [list comprehensions](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) to create a new list of every element in `mylist` whose value is one less than what it was.

There's nothing wrong with your piece of code, except if you're going to use it more than once:

```
>>> recurseDecrMap(l)
[-1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28]

>>> recurseDecrMap(l)
[-1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28]
```

To avoid this, check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-in-python-the-mutable-default-argument).

Comment: That's not recursive however (although seems like OP may have wanted this)

Comment: If I understand the OP correctly, the function MUST be recursive.

Comment: Hmm, so it must be. I'll leave this answer here, but if you want something recursive, take a look at A. Rodas' answer

Answer (score 2):

Timing comparisons of various ways to do this:

```
In [1]: import sys

In [2]: sys.setrecursionlimit(10**5)

In [3]: from so import *

In [4]: %timeit recur(range(10**4)).show()
10 loops, best of 3: 18.2 ms per loop

In [5]: %timeit recurse1(range(10**4))
1 loops, best of 3: 559 ms per loop

In [6]: %timeit recurse2(range(10**4))
1 loops, best of 3: 1e+03 ms per loop

In [7]: %timeit recurse3(range(10**4))
1 loops, best of 3: 1.02 s per loop

In [8]: %timeit recurse4(range(10**4))
1 loops, best of 3: 596 ms per loop
```

**Code:**

```
class recur:
    # No extra memory is required in this method

    def __init__(self,lis):
        self.lis=lis
        self.len=len(self.lis)
        self.rec(0)

    def show(self):
        return self.lis

    def rec(self,n):
        if n!=self.len:
            self.lis[n]-=1
            self.rec(n+1)

def recurse1(l,lis=None):
    lis=lis if lis is not None else []
    if l:
        lis.append(l[0]-1)
        return recurse1(l[1:],lis)
    else:
        return lis

def recurse2(l):
    return [l[0]-1] + recurse2(l[1:]) if l else []

def recurse3(l):  
    if len(l) == 0:  
        return []  
    else:
        return [l[0] -1] + recurse3(l[1:])

def recurse4(l, x = []):  
    if len(l) == 0:  
        return []  
    else:  
        x.append(l[0] -1)  
    recurse4(l[1:], x)  
    return x
```

Comment: Thanks again. If it's not too much trouble could you explain  if l: Is it checking if l has any elements?

Comment: Never mind. I just tested that out myself. Shouldn't have asked. Thanks

Comment: @AidanAngelini I've added some timing comparisons.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a recursive solution that can cope with large lists without hitting the recursion depth limit. By using divide and conquer the recursion depth is O(log(N)) at worst, compared to O(N) with naive recursion. Any sort of recursion is a poor choice of technique for this problem though, as it's trivially solved with a simple for-loop.

```
def dec_list(xs, a, b):
    if b == a + 1:
        xs[a] -= 1
    if a + 1 >= b: return
    mid = (a + b) // 2
    dec_list(xs, a, mid)
    dec_list(xs, mid, b)

def dec(xs):
    dec_list(xs, 0, len(xs))

xs = range(1001)
dec(xs)
print xs
```

Comment: The recursion depth is log N, but the worst-case order of complexity is still O(N).

Comment: @A.Rodas Yes, the run-time complexity is O(N). It's not possible to do better than that, since one needs to look at every element in the list.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like:

```
def dec_by_one(alist, index):
    if index == len(alist):
        return alist
    alist[index] -= 1
    return dec_by_one(alist, index + 1)


print(dec_by_one([1, 3, 4], 0)) # [0, 2, 3]
```