# Is there a way to refer to the current function in python?

Tags: python

I want a function to refer to itself. e.g. to be recursive.

So I do something like that:

```
def fib(n):
    return n if n <= 1 else fib(n-1)+fib(n-2)
```

This is fine most of the time, but `fib` does not, actually, refer to itself; it refers to the the binding of `fib` in the enclosing block. So if for some reason `fib` is reassigned, it will break:

```
>>> foo = fib
>>> fib = foo(10)
>>> x = foo(8)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 2, in fib
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

How can I prevent this from happening (from inside `fib`), if at all possible? As far as I know, the name of `fib` does not exist before the function-definition is fully executed; Are there any workarounds?

I don't have a real use case where it may actually happen; I am asking out of sheer curiosity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like [abamert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16821879/is-there-a-way-to-refer-to-the-current-function-in-python#comment24252510_16821975) said "..there is no way around the problem from inside ..".

Here's my approach:

```
def fib(n):
    def fib(n):
        return n if n <= 1 else fib(n-1)+fib(n-2)
    return fib(n)
```

Comment: @elazar it's surprising that the SO community actually allowed the code edit. Check [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/179655/clarification-of-edit-rejection#comment544033_179656).

Comment: If you are saying you are not fine with my edit, you can roll it back; I thought it will need your approval anyway.

Comment: @Elazar nope. I am perfectly fine with it, it was a good edit. Just wondering how did they approve it. Lack of consistency.

Comment: I think this answer cries for macros (mentioned in the last part of @abarnert answer).

Comment: @Elazar I have no clue of it(in python) nor [MacroPy](https://github.com/lihaoyi/macropy) that abamert mentioned. In fact I am currently in the middle of reading [this](http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/macros-standard-control-constructs.html), so I am *assuming* reading python macro's along side would be great.

Comment: If you're interested in doing this with macros, and there isn't one already in the MacroPy examples, and you can't figure out how to do it yourself, contact co-author Haoyi Li and I'm willing to bet it'll be in the examples by tomorrow.

Comment: Challenge accepted! I don't think it's general-purpose enough to go in the examples, but I'll post the snippet somewhere for people to see.

Answer (score 7):

I'd make a decorator for this

```
from functools import wraps

def selfcaller(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        return func(wrapper, *args, **kwargs)
    return wrapper
```

And use it like

```
@selfcaller
def fib(self, n):
    return n if n <= 1 else self(n-1)+self(n-2)
```

---

This is actually a readable way to define a [Fixed Point Combinator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_combinator) (or Y Combinator):

```
fix = lambda g: (lambda f: g(lambda arg: f(f)(arg))) (lambda f: g(lambda arg: f(f)(arg)))
```

usage:

```
fib = fix(lambda self: lambda n: n if n <= 1 else self(n-1)+self(n-2))
```

or:

```
@fix
def fib(self):
    return lambda n: n if n <= 1 else self(n-1)+self(n-2)
```

The binding here happens in the formal parameter, so the problem does not arise.

Comment: The way I see it, what you are suggesting is a readable way to write a [Fixed-Point Combinator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16257858/recursively-decrement-a-list-by-1/16258081#16258081). Interesting.

Comment: @Elazar Basically, yes. I haven't done a lot of pure-functional programming, so I didn't know the term. Python's decorator syntax does help in making the intent of the combinator a lot clearer.

Comment: Can I add a note about it to your answer? I like this connection.

Comment: This isn't really the same; `selfcaller` works on the actual `fib` function, but the Y combinator works on a function that _returns_ the `fib` function. The binding happens in the formal parameter of that function-creating function. Which is just a local, and there's really no reason for it to be a parameter. Also, there's no reason for the inner function to be a `lambda` instead of a `def`—in which case you've already got your local name already. Which means the Y combinator adds nothing; all you need the deco to do is call the function-creating function. Which is… exactly my answer.

Comment: @abarnert This way you don't not need the explicit deletion... I am thinking about the Y combinator. I am not sure if you are right, but if you *are* sure, feel free to edit my addition out - I don't want to be misleading.

Comment: @abarnert Since lambda calculus considers a multi-argument function `(x,y) -> z` to be equivalent to the higher-order `x -> (y -> z)`, `selfcaller` is equivalent to the Y combinator.

Comment: Theoretically it's not exactly equivalent, but for the purpose of this discussion it is. The name `fib` is incorrect *before* the application of `@fix`, but it is correct after that.

Comment: @AbeKarplus: Yes, but Python calling syntax doesn't work that way, so the Python implementations of `selfcaller` and `fix` are _not_ equivalent.

Comment: Also, there's really no need for the explicit deletion in my answer either, just as there's no reason you can't explicitly stash or delete the original `fib` here.

Comment: @AbeKarplus, do you see a way to define `fix` for a `fib(self, n)`? I can't see it.

Comment: @Elazar I'm not sure quite what you're asking. Do you want `selfcaller` as a lambda function?

Comment: No. I wonder if `@fix` could be defined to receive `fib(self, n)`, just like selfcaller.

Comment: @Elazar: Well, `fib(self, n)` doesn't return the result, it returns a function that returns the result. So, it's a question of lifting or lowering a parameter. It's easy to write a `fib(self, n)` that returns a function of no parameters that has `n` in its closure, but then `fix` has to return a function that puts its parameter into the closure of the wrapped function, instead of just passing it to the wrapped function. (This would be a lot easier to express in Haskell than English, if that's an option.) Which makes things more complicated, and I'm not sure what the benefit is.

Comment: Haskell will be welcomed... I think the question is: what is the *intrinsic* difference between receiving a tuple and currying, for the sake of `fix`/`selfcaller`'s implementation.

Comment: The intrinsic difference, from the implementation point of view, is that currying and uncurrying in Python aren't a no-op; each has to be done by explicitly, by creating another function (whether with partial, lambda, or def). Of course practically, in the case where you're already creating a function, you can sometimes collapse the extra one and the one you already have, but… I'm actually not sure how to describe that in theoretical terms.

Answer (score 4):

There's no way to do what you're trying to do. You're right that `fib` does not exist before the function definition is executed (or, worse, it exists but refers to something completely different…), which means there is no workaround *from inside `fib`* that can possibly work.*

However, if you're willing to drop that requirement, there are workarounds that *do* work. For example:

```
def _fibmaker():
    def fib(n):
        return n if n <= 1 else fib(n-1)+fib(n-2)
    return fib
fib = _fibmaker()
del _fibmaker
```

Now `fib` is referring to the binding in the closure from the local environment of a call to `_fibmaker`. Of course even *that* can be replaced if you really want to, but it's not easy (the `fib.__closure__` attribute is not writable; it's a tuple, so you can't replace any of its cells; each cell's `cell_contents` is a readonly attribute, …), and there's no way you're going to do it by accident.

There are other ways to do this (e.g., use a special placeholder inside `fib`, and a decorator that replaces the placeholder with the decorated function), and they're all about equally unobvious and ugly, which may seem to violate TOOWTDI. But in this case, the "it" is something you probably don't want to do, so it doesn't really matter.

---

Here's one way you can write a general, pure-python decorator for a function that uses `self` instead of its own name, without needing an extra `self` parameter to the function:

```
def selfcaller(func):
    env = {}
    newfunc = types.FunctionType(func.__code__, globals=env)
    env['self'] = newfunc
    return newfunc

@selfcaller
def fib(n):
    return n if n <= 1 else self(n-1)+self(n-2)
```

Of course this won't work on a function that has any free variables that are bound from `globals`, but you can fix that with a bit of introspection. And, while we're at it, we can *also* remove the need to use `self` inside the function's definition:

```
def selfcaller(func):
    env = dict(func.__globals__)
    newfunc = types.FunctionType(func.__code__, globals=env)
    env[func.__code__.co_name] = newfunc
    return newfunc
```

This is Python 3.x-specific; some of the attribute names are different in 2.x, but otherwise it's the same.

This still isn't 100% fully general. For example, if you want to be able to use it on methods so they can still call themselves even if the class or object redefines their name, you need slightly different tricks. And there are some pathological cases that might require building a new `CodeType` out of `func.__code__.co_code`. But the basic idea is the same.

---

* As far as Python is concerned, until the name is bound, it doesn't exist… but obviously, under the covers, the interpreter has to know the name of the function you're defining. And at least some interpreters offer non-portable ways to get at that information.

For example, in CPython 3.x, you can very easily get the name of the function currently being defined—it's just `sys._getframe().f_code.co_name`.

Of course this won't directly do you any good, because nothing (or the wrong thing) is bound to that name. But notice that `f_code` in there. That's the current frame's code object. Of course you can't call a code object directly, but you can do so indirectly, either by generating a new function out of it, or by using [`bytecodehacks`](http://bytecodehacks.sourceforge.net/bch-docs/bch/index.html).

For example:

```
def fib2(n):
    f = sys._getframe()
    fib2 = types.FunctionType(f.f_code, globals=globals())
    return n if n<=1 else fib2(n-1)+fib2(n-2)
```

Again, this won't handle every pathological case… but the only way I can think of to do so is to actually keep a circular reference to the frame, or at least its globals (e.g., by passing `globals=f.f_globals`), which seems like a very bad idea.

See [Frame Hacks](http://farmdev.com/src/secrets/framehack/) for more clever things you can do.

---

Finally, if you're willing to step out of Python entirely, you can create an import hook that preprocesses or compiles your code from a Python custom-extended with, say, `defrec` into pure Python and/or bytecode.

And if you're thinking "But that sounds like it would be a lot nicer as a macro than as a preprocessor hack, if only Python had macros"… then you'll probably prefer to use a preprocessor hack that gives Python macros, like [MacroPy](https://github.com/lihaoyi/macropy), and then write your extensions as macros.

Comment: (If it "exists but refers to something completely different" it will not make any difference - this name will be assigned shortly.)

Comment: @Elazar: Well, yes, but the point is that either (a) there's no existing thing you _could_ bind to—or (b) there _is_, but it's something you don't _want_ to bind to. Either way, there is no way around the problem from inside `fib`.

Comment: I see. I thought maybe there's some sort of reflection thing I am not familiar with... Your answer does seem like the straight-forward way.

Comment: @Elazar: Well, from inside `fib` there's nothing to reflect on. But yes, from _outside_—e.g., in a decorator—you can get all kinds of information, such as a list of the unbound names in the function. (The [`inspect` module docs](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/inspect.html) show all of the easily-reflectable stuff in a nice chart at the top.) And you could use that to make a decorator that doesn't require adding an explicit `self` parameter like Abe Karplus's, if you wanted.

Comment: Isn't there anything like an access to the state of the interpreter? (Not that I would use anything like it in real life of course).

Comment: Can you give an example for your last suggestion - not using an explicit self?

Comment: @Elazar: If you want to write code that only works in CPython, as opposed to pure Python, then yes, you can use `sys._getframe(1)`. See [Frame Hacks](http://farmdev.com/src/secrets/framehack/) for some examples of what you can do.

Comment: @Elazar: For not using an explicit self… the idea is to use `types.FunctionTypes` to build a new function with the original's code, but a special `globals` environment. Give me a sec and I'll hammer out the details.

Comment: so it would only fit a global function, I guess. or maybe you can pass nonlocals too?

Comment: @Elazar: Well, you can pass `closure`. From you interpreter, type `help(types.FunctionType)` and `help(types.CodeType)` for full details on what you can substitute.

Comment: great read that was. That's why I like asking the most obvious of questions. That way I get a chance to learn a lot more and get ideas into right perspective.

Answer (score 1):

Someone asked me for a macro based solution for this, so here it is:

```
# macropy/my_macro.py
from macropy.core.macros import *

macros = Macros()

@macros.decorator()
def recursive(tree, **kw):
    tree.decorator_list = []

    wrapper = FunctionDef(
        name=tree.name,
        args=tree.args,
        body=[],
        decorator_list=tree.decorator_list
    )

    return_call = Return(
        Call(
            func = Name(id=tree.name),
            args = tree.args.args,
            keywords = [],
            starargs = tree.args.vararg,
            kwargs = tree.args.kwarg
        )
    )

    return_call = parse_stmt(unparse_ast(return_call))[0]

    wrapper.body = [tree, return_call]

    return wrapper
```

This can be used as follows:

```
>>> import macropy.core.console
0=[]=====> MacroPy Enabled <=====[]=0
>>> from macropy.my_macro import macros, recursive
>>> @recursive
... def fib(n):
...     return n if n <= 1 else fib(n-1)+fib(n-2)
...
>>> foo = fib
>>> fib = foo(10)
>>> x = foo(8)
>>> x
21
```

It basically does exactly the wrapping that hus787 gave:

- Create a new statement which does `return fib(...)`, which uses the argument list of the original function as the `...`
- Create a new `def`, with the same name, same args, same decorator_list as the old one
- Place the old function, together followed by the `return` statement, in the body of the new functiondef
- Strip the original function of its decorators (I assume you'd want to decorate the wrapper instead)

The `parse_stmt(unparse_ast(return_call))[0]` rubbish is a quick hack to get stuff to work (you actually can't just copy the `argument` AST from the param list of the function and use them in a `Call` AST) but that's just detail.

To show that it's actually doing that, you can add a `print unparse_ast` statement to see what the transformed function looks like:

```
@macros.decorator()
def recursive(tree, **kw):
    ...
    print unparse_ast(wrapper)
    return wrapper
```

which, when run as above, prints

```
def fib(n):

    def fib(n):
        return (n if (n <= 1) else (fib((n - 1)) + fib((n - 2))))
    return fib(n)
```

Looks like exactly what you want! It should work for any function, with multiple args, kwargs, defaults, etc., but I'm too lazy to test. Working with the AST is a bit verbose, and [MacroPy](https://github.com/lihaoyi/macropy) is still super-experimental, but i think it's pretty neat.